# type of c array name in gdb

Tags: c, arrays

```
int arr[4][2][3][6];
```

when running gdb to inspect the type of arr( the array name)

```
(gdb) wha arr
type = int [4][2][3][6]
```

As far as I know, when in an expression(exept used as operand of 'sizeof' or '&'), compiler treat array name as a pointer to the first element of the array. So, I was expecting `type = int (*)[2][3][6]`

Interestingly, if I inspect this:

```
(gdb) wha arr+1
type = int (*)[2][3][6]
```

you see that the output is as expected!
Here I want to know is it just a displaying style of gdb or the type of an array name is really `int [4][2][3][6]`?

BTW, I have a guess of why gdb said the type is `int [4][2][3][6]`, you see,

```
(gdb) wha &arr
type = int (*)[4][2][3][6]
```

so, is `&arr` is pointer to `int [4][2][3][6]` then arr should be `int [4][2][3][6]`....

Comment: What are you asking? The type of an array is its type, not the type it decays to. You can see this in C too with the `&` operator, the `sizeof` operator, and in the GCC extension `__typeof__`.

Comment: After thinking of your response, I got the point that, when I ask gdb to tell me the type of the array name, the array name itself isn't in a `expression`! Thus it's not treated as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: By the way, you can use +0 rather than +1 to make it decay without changing its value.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler uses the name as a pointer to the first element when you use in a context that expects a pointer. But gdb is correct about the actual type of the symbols you're passing.

arr+1 is &arr[1], which is a pointer to the 3-dimensional array shown.

arr itself is an array of those; i.e. a 4-dimensional array.

Comment: I guess arr+1 should be &arr[1]？Because `arr[1] equales *(arr+1)`